# Java Hashtable saving into a file

Tags: java, file, hashtable

I wrote this diary that a user can pick a date, write some text for that date and save it.
the text is stored in hash table for each date .

I am trying now to save the hash table in a file.
I have few questions about the code I wrote:

1. The code is not working, some error that I don't understand:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Q2.MainPanel.updateHashFromFile(MainPanel.java:133)
at Q2.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:46)
at Q2.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

1. eclipse always warn me about adding throws to every method that I write something that deals with files. the way I did it you think is the right way?
2. Is is good way to declare the FileInputStream,ObjectInputStream,File as global parameters like I did? or there is more recommended way of doing so?
3. Do you think is good way to write together in the same class the panel and GUI treatment and data and saving treatment like I did? or it would be better to split those into few classes?

This is the code:

```
package Q2;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    private String[] days = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
    private String[] months = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"};
    private String[] years = {"2014","2015","2016","2017","2018"};
    private Font myFont = new Font("david", Font.BOLD, 24);
    JButton btnSave, btnShow;
    JComboBox daysBox,yearsBox,monthsBox;
    private static Hashtable<MyDate, String> diary;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private static File file;
    private static FileInputStream in;
    private static FileOutputStream out;
    private static ObjectInputStream streamIn;
    private static ObjectOutputStream streamOut;

    //Constructor for main panel with BorderLayout with panels inside
    public MainPanel () throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(getDateButtons(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(myFont);
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(getSaveShowButtons(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        file = new File("MyDiary");
        updateHashFromFile();


        diary = new Hashtable<MyDate, String>();
    }

    //create and return the NORTH date buttons panel
    private JPanel getDateButtons(){
        JPanel dateButtons = new JPanel();

        //create and add the days JCombobox
        daysBox = new JComboBox(days);
        daysBox.setFont(myFont);
        dateButtons.add(daysBox);

        //create and add the months JCombobox
        monthsBox = new JComboBox(months);
        monthsBox.setFont(myFont);
        dateButtons.add(monthsBox);

        //create and add the year JCombobox
        yearsBox = new JComboBox(years);
        yearsBox.setFont(myFont);
        dateButtons.add(yearsBox);

        return dateButtons;
    }

    //
    private JPanel getSaveShowButtons(){
        JPanel saveShowButtons = new JPanel();
        ButtonListener lis = new ButtonListener();

        btnSave = new JButton("save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(lis);
        btnSave.setFont(myFont);
        saveShowButtons.add(btnSave);

        btnShow = new JButton("show");
        btnShow.addActionListener(lis);
        btnShow.setFont(myFont);
        saveShowButtons.add(btnShow);

        return saveShowButtons;

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource()==btnSave){
                int day = Integer.parseInt((String)daysBox.getSelectedItem());
                int month = Integer.parseInt((String)monthsBox.getSelectedItem());
                int year = Integer.parseInt((String)yearsBox.getSelectedItem());
                MyDate date = new MyDate(day, month, year);
                System.out.println(date);
                diary.put(date,textArea.getText());
                textArea.setText(null);
                try {
                    updateHashToFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource()==btnShow){
                int day = Integer.parseInt((String)daysBox.getSelectedItem());
                int month = Integer.parseInt((String)monthsBox.getSelectedItem());
                int year = Integer.parseInt((String)yearsBox.getSelectedItem());
                MyDate date = new MyDate(day, month, year);
                String s = diary.get(date);
                if (s!=null)
                    textArea.setText(s+" ");
                else textArea.setText(" ");
            }

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void updateHashFromFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();
        else {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            streamIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            diary = (Hashtable<MyDate, String>)streamIn.readObject();
        }

    }

    //update the file with the new hash table diary data
    private static void updateHashToFile() throws IOException{
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        streamOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        streamOut.writeObject(diary);
    }
}
```

MyDate class code:

```
package Q2;

public class MyDate {

    private static int[] numOfDays = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}; //Number of days on each month
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    //Constructor for date object
    public MyDate(int day, int month, int year){
        if(day<=numOfDays[month-1]){ //In case chosen day that not exist in the month the last day of the month will be chosen
            this.day = day;
        }else this.day = numOfDays[month-1];
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    //@override toString
    public String toString(){
        return this.day+"/"+ this.month+"/"+this.year;
    }

    //@override equals
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if(this.day==((MyDate)other).day && this.month==((MyDate)other).month && this.year==((MyDate)other).year)
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    public int hashCode() {
        return ((day * 31) + month) * 31 + year; 
    }
}
```

Main class code:

```
package Q2;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Diary");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't get any warnings but the ClassNotFoundException exception looks useless.
2. Avoid using static variables for streams. You can declare them locally in this specific code, but it is not a rule. Instead you can declare static final the days, months and years since they are constants and never change.
3. It is your choice and depends how legible the code will be at the end.

Be sure that you close the steams.

Here is the modified code with my suggestions. I temporarily replaced MyDate with java.util.Date so I can compile the code, you can ignore it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
//import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    private static final String[] days = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
    private static final String[] months = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"};
    private static final String[] years = {"2014","2015","2016","2017","2018"};
    private static final Font myFont = new Font("david", Font.BOLD, 24);
    JButton btnSave, btnShow;
    JComboBox daysBox,yearsBox,monthsBox;
    private Hashtable<java.util.Date, String> diary;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private File file;

    //Constructor for main panel with BorderLayout with panels inside
    public MainPanel () throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(getDateButtons(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(myFont);
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(getSaveShowButtons(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        file = new File("MyDiary");
        updateHashFromFile();


        diary = new Hashtable<java.util.Date, String>();
    }

    //create and return the NORTH date buttons panel
    private JPanel getDateButtons(){
        JPanel dateButtons = new JPanel();

        //create and add the days JCombobox
        daysBox = new JComboBox(days);
        daysBox.setFont(myFont);
        dateButtons.add(daysBox);

        //create and add the months JCombobox
        monthsBox = new JComboBox(months);
        monthsBox.setFont(myFont);
        dateButtons.add(monthsBox);

        //create and add the year JCombobox
        yearsBox = new JComboBox(years);
        yearsBox.setFont(myFont);
        dateButtons.add(yearsBox);

        return dateButtons;
    }

    //
    private JPanel getSaveShowButtons(){
        JPanel saveShowButtons = new JPanel();
        ButtonListener lis = new ButtonListener();

        btnSave = new JButton("save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(lis);
        btnSave.setFont(myFont);
        saveShowButtons.add(btnSave);

        btnShow = new JButton("show");
        btnShow.addActionListener(lis);
        btnShow.setFont(myFont);
        saveShowButtons.add(btnShow);

        return saveShowButtons;

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource()==btnSave){
                int day = Integer.parseInt((String)daysBox.getSelectedItem());
                int month = Integer.parseInt((String)monthsBox.getSelectedItem());
                int year = Integer.parseInt((String)yearsBox.getSelectedItem());
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(day, month, year);
                System.out.println(date);
                diary.put(date,textArea.getText());
                textArea.setText(null);
                try {
                    updateHashToFile();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource()==btnShow){
                int day = Integer.parseInt((String)daysBox.getSelectedItem());
                int month = Integer.parseInt((String)monthsBox.getSelectedItem());
                int year = Integer.parseInt((String)yearsBox.getSelectedItem());
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(day, month, year);
                String s = diary.get(date);
                if (s!=null)
                    textArea.setText(s+" ");
                else textArea.setText(" ");
            }

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void updateHashFromFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();
        else {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream streamIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            diary = (Hashtable<java.util.Date, String>)streamIn.readObject();
            streamIn.close();
        }

    }

    //update the file with the new hash table diary data
    private void updateHashToFile() throws IOException{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream streamOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        streamOut.writeObject(diary);
        streamOut.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but when I try to compile it I get:

Comment: Thanks! but when I try to compile it I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Q2.MainPanel.updateHashFromFile(MainPanel.java:129)
 at Q2.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:42)
 at Q2.Main.main(Main.java:13)

Comment: even with the stream declared locally?